# how to fix a yes no dialog box

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a dialogue box to ask the user if they worked overtime and if yes then i ask how many hours and if not it carries on with the rest of the code, but i don't know if I'm doing it right, if someone could provide the right code to perform this task that would be great.

Ive tried this method below but there was something wrong with that code too:

```
  int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
  int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Did he/she work overtime",dialogButton);
  if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
     {
        int oTime = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many hours did he/she work overtime?"));
     }
```

//This is the code im currently using but im not sure how to do the if statement

```
  int selection;
  boolean isYes;

  selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Did you he/she work overtime?");
  if (selection == isYes)
  {
     int oHours = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many overtime hours did he/she work?"));

   }
```

Comment: Can you outline exactly what's going wrong? Do you get an error? Does the code not execute? Try placing print statements at each spot and tell us what gets printed out.

Comment: You can't compare an int with a boolean.

Comment: You have to initialize isYes to something if you want to compare to its value.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) the first code snippet is correct. If you are having problems with that please describe what went wrong and what you want it to do differently. Also, what about just asking for the total number of hours and deciding from that if there is overtime or not?

Comment: its just the if statement thats not working, if the user clicks yes  in the dialogue box i want the program to then ask how many overtime hours were worked, the if statement is wrong i know because you cannot compare an int with a boolean so that bit is not executing so how could i fix that @Jeeter

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ,  in the first code the error message that comes up is:   Wages2.java:9: error: no suitable method found for showConfirmDialog(<null>,String,int)
      int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Did he/she work overtime",dialogButton);
                                    ^
    method JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that additional information